# Box2D DynamicBody collision with KinematicBody

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I've a Dynamic Body that collides with Kinematic Bodies being thrown at it.
In a particular situation (a different kind of Kinematic Body lets say) I still want the collision detection by the `ContactListener` but without affecting the Dynamic Body with the collision resultant forces.
Is is possible? If so how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is stretching my memory a bit, and you haven't posted an MCVE that we can play with, but I believe you can use a contact callback and the beginContact() or preSolve() methods to "cancel" the collision.

Sources:
http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-anatomy
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15985/how-can-i-cancel-a-contact-in-a-b2contactlistener

You might also consider using a sensor instead of a body, depending on what you're trying to do.

Edit: Some more sources seem to confirm, maybe my memory isn't as bad as I thought!
[Set contact enabled in box2d andengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703285/set-contact-enabled-in-box2d-andengine)

[How to detect collision but do not collide in box2d?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062252/how-to-detect-collision-but-do-not-collide-in-box2d)

Comment: Hi Kevin! Thanks for your help, I was going to answer myself because I found this same solution after reading the interface ContactListener "javadoc". Yes I'm disabling the collision for a short period of time and its working. I still have a doubt. Should I put my disable logic inside beginContact() or preSolve()?

Comment: I could try googling some more, but the honest answer is to just try one and see if it works. And if it doesn't, try the other.